# como excluir um objeto do json com python?

Tags: python, json

```
data = ler_repositorio()
print (data)
excluir_funcionrio = input('quem você quer excluir: ')

print('Tem certeza?')
print('1 - continuar')
print('2 - voltar')
opção_adquirida = int(input('Escolha: '))

if opção_adquirida == 1:
    for funcionario in data:
        if funcionario == excluir_funcionrio:

            print (funcionario)


elif opção_adquirida == 2:
    pass
```

Eu presciso excluir um objeto, neste caso excluir um funcionário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso os funcionários estejam armazenados numa lista, pode experimentar o seguite:

```py
data = ["João", "Pedro", "Maria"]
print (data)

funcionario_a_excluir = input('Quem quer excluir? ')

print('Tem certeza?')
print('1 - continuar')
print('2 - voltar')
opcao_adquirida = int(input('Escolha: '))

if opcao_adquirida == 1:
    data.remove(funcionario_a_excluir)

print(data)
```

Veja [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists/11520540) para mais informações sobre remoção de elementos específicos de listas.

Comment: +1, obrigado por me ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria desta forma:

```
excluir_funcionrio = input('quem você quer excluir: ')

print('Tem certeza?')
print('1 - continuar')
print('2 - voltar')

if opção_adquirida == 1:
   for funcionario in enumerate(data):
       if data[funcionario[0]]['nome'] == excluir_funcionário:
          del data[funcionario[0]]
```

O método `enumerate()` retorna uma tupla com o índice do elemento na lista e o conteúdo da mesma lista. Por isso, quando da comparação entre o funcionário apontado para exclusão e o elemento corrente do `for`, é preciso informar a posição 0.

Se você der um `print(funcionario)` dentro do `for`, verá a tupla que informei. Uma vez que você saiba o índice do elemento que quer excluir na lista, basta executar o comando de exclusão. Posteriormente, é só gerar o arquivo JSON novamente com a nova lista.